# MATLAB: Select elements in a vector multiple times with different index list

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

INPUT: a logical row vector `u` with length `n`, say `[1,0,1,1,0]`; and a logical matrix `M` of size m-by-n, say `[1,0,0,1,1;0 0 0 1 1]`.

OUTPUT: a logical matrix of size m-by-n, the first row of which is obtained by applying the first row of matrix `M` as "selector", that is, `[1,0,0,1,0];` and the second row is, similarly, `[0 0 0 1 0]`.

The row vector is 20000 long, and the the matrix is 30-by-20000. This will repeat 1000 times, and I want something costs less than 1 second.

I've tried `repmat`, `bsxfun`, and element-wise multiplication, no luck. Guess there is a simple way to "choose" these elements all at once, since they are all logical values.

Comment: Depending on the size of `n` and how sparse the selector `u` is, your resulting logical array is going to be mostly zeros, with many rows that are totally zero. Can you reformulate the problem to take advantage of this? Are you using `M` to index into an array of data?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest I can give you is 4 seconds at the moment (on my machine). I'm not 100% sure if you've tried this or not, but here you go anyway.

I have an m-file `randbool.m` with these contents, to generate the test data.

```
function x = randbool(m,n)
x = logical(rand(m,n) < 0.5);
```

Generate the data for testing:

```
>> u = randbool(1,20000);
>> M = randbool(30,20000);
```

I can think of three ways to loop over the rows of M (use `bsxfun`, use `repmat`, use a loop) and two ways to pull out the elements you want (conjunction `&`, or pointwise multiplication with `.*`). The fastest is the combination of `bsxfun` and conjunction:

#### Bsxfun / conjunction

```
>> tic, for i=1:1000, bsxfun(@and,u,M); end, toc
Elapsed time is 4.068684 seconds.
```

#### Bsxfun / multiplication

```
>> tic, for i=1:1000, bsxfun(@times,u,M); end, toc
Elapsed time is 4.856784 seconds.
```

#### Repmat / conjunction

```
>> tic, for i=1:1000, utmp=repmat(u,30,1); M&utmp; end, toc
Elapsed time is 7.305158 seconds.
```

#### Repmat / multiplication

```
>> tic, for i=1:1000, utmp=repmat(u,30,1); M.*utmp; end, toc
Elapsed time is 8.117164 seconds.
```

#### Looping / conjunction

```
>> tic, for i=1:1000, for j = 1:30, out(j,:)=u&M(j,:); end; end, toc
Elapsed time is 7.110872 seconds.
```

#### Looping / multiplication

```
>> tic, for i=1:1000, for j = 1:30, out(j,:)=u.*M(j,:); end; end, toc
Elapsed time is 8.322888 seconds.
```

Comment: +1 nice summary. @DavidTan A note: the order of matrix/vector parameters in `bsxfun` matters for performance. The above is 3 times faster on my computer than `bsxfun(@and,M,u);`. You might want to be careful. Also, Chris's original version runs in `0.6s` on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bitwise and operation. Perhaps something like this would work:

```
utemp=repmat(u,1,size(m,2));
output=M&utemp;
```

I should add that for that large of a matrix, you might run into memory problems. Essentially you need 3 copies of the 600K element matrix, which could add up.

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions are overcomplicating things.

All you need to do is zero out the entries in the non-chosen columns...

```
M(:,~u)=0;
```

That's it. Ten measly characters. Chris Taylor's solution using bsxfun with @and is a little slower, other methods are worse.

```
octave:8> u = logical(rand(1,20000)<0.5);
octave:9> M = logical(rand(30,20000)<0.5);
octave:10> tic, for i=1:1000, N=M; N(:,~u)=0; end, toc
Elapsed time is 0.66 seconds.
octave:11> tic, for i=1:1000, N=M; N=bsxfun(@and,u,N); end, toc
Elapsed time is 0.82 seconds.
octave:12> tic, for i=1:1000, N=bsxfun(@and,u,M); end, toc
Elapsed time is 0.8 seconds.
```

Note that I've used "N=M" to standardise the result, because this method acts directly on the vector, but the assignment isn't adding anything significant to the time.